# como se puede abrir una aplicación como administrador en mac

Tags: vscode, macos

ya intente dar permisos a VSCode para abrirla en mac os high sierra pero aun así no me deja arrancar pues dice que no se puede escribir en la carpeta de app support y estoy en la cuenta de administrador

gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

desde la terminal puedes iniciar VSCode con el comando `sudo code` o `sudo code ./` para que te cargue la carpeta actual en VSCode.

Si eso no te funciona podrías intentar cambiar los permisos de escritura de la carpeta en la que quieres trabajar.

Espero que haya sido de ayuda.